# Rolling a die/recording findings to find if S is even,odd or both

Tags: probability

suppose you roll a fair six sided die repeatedly and the rolls are recorded. When two consecutive rolls are identical the process is ended. Let S denote the sum of all rolls made. Is S more likely to be even, odd, or just as likely even as odd?

I am stuck trying to figure out which way to approach this question
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that a sequence of rolls with no repeats is *good*. If $n$ is odd, exactly half of the good sequences of length $n$ have an even number of odd rolls; this can be seen as follows. If $r=\langle r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle$ is a good sequence, let $\hat r=\langle 7-r_1,\ldots,7-r_n\rangle$, and note that $r$ has an even number of odd rolls if and only if $\hat r$ has an odd number of odd rolls. If $E_n$ is the set of good sequence of length $n$ with an even number of odd rolls, and $O_n$ is the set of good sequence of length $n$ with an odd number of odd rolls, the map $E_n\to O_n:r\mapsto\hat r$ is a bijection, so $|E_n|=|O_n|$. It follows that if the sequence of tosses is of odd length, it is equally likely to have an odd or an even total.

Things are more complicated when $n$ is even. Let $p_n$ be the probability of rolling a sequence in $E_n$, and let $q_n$ be the probability of rolling a sequence in $O_n$. In order to roll a sequence in $E_{n+2}$, we must either roll a sequence in $E_n$ followed by one in $E_2$, or roll a sequence in $O_n$ followed by one in $O_2$. Moreover, the $n$-th and $(n+1)$-st rolls must be different, and the $n$-th roll is equally likely to be even or odd. (The map $r\mapsto\hat r$ can be used to justify that last assertion.) This means that

$$p_{n+2}=p_n\left(\frac4{36}+\frac6{36}\right)+q_n\left(\frac9{36}+\frac6{36}\right)=\frac5{36}(2p_n+3q_n)\;.$$

A similar analysis shows that

$$q_{n+2}=q_n\left(\frac4{36}+\frac6{36}\right)+p_n\left(\frac9{36}+\frac6{36}\right)=\frac5{36}(2q_n+3p_n)$$

and hence that

$$p_{n+2}-q_{n+2}=\frac5{36}(q_n-p_n)=-\frac5{36}(p_n-q_n)\;.$$

It follows that

$$p_{2n}-q_{2n}=\left(-\frac5{36}\right)^{n-1}(p_2-q_2)=-\frac16\left(-\frac5{36}\right)^{n-1}$$

for $n\ge 1$, since $p_2=\frac13$ and $q_2=\frac12$ by direct calculation.

Let $p_n'$ be the probability of an even total and a sequence of length $n+2$, and let $q_n'$ be the probability of an odd total and a sequence of length $n+2$. By direct calculation $p_0'=\frac16$ and $q_0'=0$, and it’s also easy to see that $$p_{2n}'=\frac5{36}p_{2n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q_{2n}'=\frac5{36}q_{2n}$$ for $n\ge 1$: the $(2n+1)$-st toss must differ from the $(2n)$-th toss, and the last toss must match the previous one. Then the probability of getting an even total and a sequence of even length exceeds the probability of getting an odd total and a sequence of even length by

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}(p_{2n}'-q_{2n}')&=\frac16+\frac5{36}\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(-\frac16\right)\left(-\frac5{36}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac16\left(1+\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(-\frac5{36}\right)^n\right)\\
&=\frac16\left(1+\frac{-5/36}{41/36}\right)\\
&=\frac16\left(1-\frac5{41}\right)\\
&>0\;.
\end{align*}$$

In short, odd and even totals are equally likely when the sequence has odd length, and even totals are more likely than odd totals when the sequence has even length, so overall even totals are more likely than odd totals.

Comment: Would of never thought of it this way thanks so much I needed this for my exam tomorrow.

Comment: @Eduardo: You're very welcome. I keep thinking that there ought to be a better way, but I've not found one.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There is a special case where the first two rolls match.

Comment: That’s useful, but it’s not enough: you have to show that the initial bias isn’t wiped out by the results for longer sequences of rolls.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say more likely to be even assuming by fair you mean each of the $6$ sides is equally likely and that they are numbered $1$ thru $6$.